# Java - Nested For loop - Better way to append to File for every System.out.println

Tags: java

I am using the below code to generate some Test Data which gets the job done. No problems here.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

class GenerateTestData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File outfile = new File("dbscript_output.sql");

        if (outfile.exists()) {
            outfile.delete();
        }
        int totalCluster = 2;
        int totalAgency = totalCluster * 10;
        int totalProgramArea = totalAgency * 20;
        int totalUsers = totalProgramArea * 100;

        for (int numCluster = 1; numCluster <= totalCluster; ++numCluster) {
            System.out.println("\nCluster__________________________" + numCluster);
            
            writeToFile("Cluster__________________________" + numCluster);
            for (int numAgency = 1; numAgency <= totalAgency; ++numAgency) {
                System.out.println("\n\tCluster_" + numCluster + "_Agency_" + numAgency);
                
                writeToFile("\n\tCluster_" + numCluster + "_Agency_" + numAgency);
                for (int numProgramArea = 1; numProgramArea <= totalProgramArea; ++numProgramArea) {
                    System.out.println("\n\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea);
                    
                    writeToFile("\n\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea);
                    for (int numUser = 1; numUser <= totalUsers; ++numUser) {
                        System.out.println("\n\t\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_" + "ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea
                                + "_User_" + numUser);
                        
                        writeToFile("\n\t\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_" + "ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea
                                + "_User_" + numUser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String data) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("dbscript_output.sql");
        FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
        br.write(data);
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to achieve it? Does Java 7/8/11 has any better API to do it? I am open for any shorter/smarter way of doing it using Java. The sample shown here is just a few elements. I have 16 Entities for which I have to prepare Test Data and all of them are connected (related). Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Please allow me to reframe the question.

Is there any shorter/smarter way to achieve above using pure Core Java 1.8+ ? Where I can club (merge) 'for' loop and 'writeToFile'? (in one liner may be?) Appreciate all for your help.

Comment: Why don't you put the `System.out.println` command inside `writeToFile` so you don't have to write every message in code twice?

Comment: Yeah that is what I am doing. Please take a relook. Please explain if I mis-understood.

Comment: I mean, put `System.out.println(data)` inside `writeToFile` and that takes the place of all the `System.out.println` statements currently in your code.

Comment: You have to write these test in pure Java without any frameworks or orm?

Comment: Pure  java please @MrFisherman.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624114/is-there-any-way-to-flat-these-nested-intstreams-into-one-is-there-shorter-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As our colleague mentioned above you can use try with resources as below (so you dont have to close every input stream). You can also short/change nested for loops with streams but it isn't clearer solution and you have to improve it.

```
public class GenerateTestData {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File outfile = new File("dbscript_output2.sql");

    if (outfile.exists()) {
        outfile.delete();
    }
    int totalCluster = 2;
    int totalAgency = totalCluster * 10;
    int totalProgramArea = totalAgency * 20;
    int totalUsers = totalProgramArea * 100;


    IntStream.range(0, totalCluster).forEach(numCluster->{
        writeToFile("Cluster__________________________" + numCluster);
        IntStream.range(0, totalAgency).forEach(numAgency->{
            writeToFile("\n\tCluster_" + numCluster + "_Agency_" + numAgency);
            IntStream.range(0, totalProgramArea).forEach(numProgramArea->
                    IntStream.range(0,totalUsers).forEach(numUser->{
                        writeToFile("\n\t\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_" + "ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea
                                + "_User_" + numUser);
                    }));
        });
    });
}

private static void writeToFile(String data) {
    File file = new File("dbscript_output2.sql");
    try(FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr)) {
        br.write(data);
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to only open the file once (as opposed to opening and closing it for each entry).

Also, you can use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to ensure that the output file is closed automatically.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


class GenerateTestData  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int totalCluster = 2;
        int totalAgency = totalCluster * 10;
        int totalProgramArea = totalAgency * 20;
        int totalUsers = totalProgramArea * 100;

        // try-with-resources statement
        try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("dbscript_output.sql"))) {

            for (int numCluster = 1; numCluster <= totalCluster; ++numCluster) {
                writeOutput(br, "Cluster__________________________" + numCluster);

                for (int numAgency = 1; numAgency <= totalAgency; ++numAgency) {
                    writeOutput(br,"\n\tCluster_" + numCluster + "_Agency_" + numAgency);

                    for (int numProgramArea = 1; numProgramArea <= totalProgramArea; ++numProgramArea) {
                        writeOutput(br,"\n\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea);

                        for (int numUser = 1; numUser <= totalUsers; ++numUser) {
                            writeOutput(br,"\n\t\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_" + "ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea
                                    + "_User_" + numUser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void writeOutput(BufferedWriter br, String data) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(data);
        br.write(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this second best answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the alternative below the nested loops have been refactored into separate methods and the file is opened just once and closed once you're done with it. It's not shorter but perhaps a bit more readable. Anyway, hope this gives you some inspiration.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class GenerateTestData {
    static int TOTAL_CLUSTER = 2;
    static int TOTAL_AGENCY = TOTAL_CLUSTER * 2;
    static int TOTAL_PROGRAM_AREA = TOTAL_AGENCY * 2;
    static int TOTAL_USERS = TOTAL_PROGRAM_AREA * 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File outfile = new File("dbscript_output2.sql");

        if (outfile.exists()) {
            outfile.delete();
        }

        try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outfile, true))) {
            createClusters(str -> writeLine(br, str));
        }
    }

    private static void writeLine(BufferedWriter writer, String data) {
        try {
            System.out.println(data);
            writer.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void createClusters(Consumer<String> consumer) {
        IntStream.range(1, TOTAL_CLUSTER).forEach(numCluster -> {
            consumer.accept("Cluster__________________________" + numCluster);
            createAgencies(consumer, numCluster);
        });
    }

    private static void createAgencies(Consumer<String> consumer, int numCluster) {
        IntStream.range(1, TOTAL_AGENCY).forEach(numAgency -> {
            consumer.accept("\n\tCluster_" + numCluster + "_Agency_" + numAgency);
            createProgramAreas(consumer, numAgency);
        });
    }

    private static void createProgramAreas(Consumer<String> consumer, int numAgency) {
        IntStream.range(1, TOTAL_PROGRAM_AREA).forEach(numProgramArea -> {
            consumer.accept("\n\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea);
            createUsers(consumer, numAgency, numProgramArea);
        });
    }

    private static void createUsers(Consumer<String> consumer, int numAgency, int numProgramArea) {
        IntStream.range(1, TOTAL_USERS).forEach(numUser -> {
            consumer.accept("\n\t\t\tAgency_" + numAgency + "_" + "ProgramArea_" + numProgramArea + "_User_" + numUser);
        });
    }
}
```